# How to access cell values in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Using `openpyxl`, I am trying to access certain cell values in a range to change their values. Specifically, I would like to change their values to the value of the first cell in each range. For example, in the example below, we have a merged cell range of 'B3:B9'. I want to fill in each cell in this range with the first cell (B3)'s value.

```
def fill_in(rows,first_cell,last_cell):
     #Take first cell's value
     first_value = str(first_cell.value)
     #Copy and fill/assign this value into each cell of the range
     for cell in rows:
         print(cell) ##E.g. (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B3>,)  
         print(cell.value) ##I get error here: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
         cell.value = first_value  ##Same error here. 

wb2 = load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
sheets = wb2.sheetnames #list of sheetnames
for i,sheet in enumerate(sheets): #for each sheet
    ws = wb2[sheets[i]]
    range_list = ws.merged_cell_ranges
    for _range in range_list:
        first_cell = ws[_range.split(':')[0]] #first cell of each range
        last_cell = ws[_range.split(':')[1]]
        rows = ws[_range] #big set of sets; each cell within each range
        fill_in(list(rows),first_cell,last_cell)
```

For reference, `rows` looks like this:
`((<Cell 'Sheet1'.B3>,), (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B4>,), (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B5>,), (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B6>,), (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B7>,), (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B8>,), (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B9>,))`

How can I resolve this error? In each range, how can I successfully assign each cell's value with the first cell's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in you printout you have `AttributeError: 'tuple' object ...`, and your cell is printing like `(<Cell 'Sheet1'.B3>,)`, so your actual variable holds a tuple, but you are treating it like it is the cell. You need to unpack the tuple to get to the cell-variable.

if you do:

```
for cell, in rows:
    ...
```

it's one way of unpacking, or:

```
for tmp in rows:
    cell = tmp[0]
```

is another.
btw,

```
sheets = wb2.sheetnames #list of sheetnames
for i,sheet in enumerate(sheets): #for each sheet
    ws = wb2[sheets[i]]
```

that section is not very pythonic, the following should do the same...

```
for sheet in wb2.sheetnames:
    ws = wb2[sheet]
```

Comment: @ ahed87 - I understand that your first solution `for cell, in rows:` unpacks the tuple. Can you explain how it unpacks -- more particularly in how the comma plays the role in this unpacking?

Comment: for simplicity let's say that unpacking must be done one to one (not true on py36). Unpacking with assignment, as well as in for-loop, is done with comma. This means the following `a, b, c = (0, 1, 2)` is a valid unpacking. In your case you need to trigger the unpacking and you only have one element, hence `a, = (0,)`. The alternative is just to an index lookup with `a = (0,)[0]`.

Comment: @ ahed87 - I tried your first solution (`for cell, in rows:`) and I am getting this error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)`. I assume this is because there is more than 1 element in tuple? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: yepp, which python are you on? that line worked for me with a test case on py36, so it's a bit strange if your printout of the content of the variable is correct. The general principle about unpacking is what it is, so you just need to match it correctly to what you actually have in your variables. Or keep the loop as you have it and do an index lookup within the loop.

Comment: @ ahed87 - I am in Python 3.6.2.

Comment: well, then I doubt that your printout of the content is still the same... This line should print `0 1` on your computer `for i, in ((0,), (1,)): print(i)`. If so, then please double check the printout of the `cell` variable. Also I'm not really running your example, since that's not possible, for that you would have to explain the detailed structure and content of the excel (including merged cells). It does not need to be the real data, just placeholders in right structure.

Comment: @ ahed87 - How do you conduct an index lookup within the for loop?